# How to read Avro files (generated from Java class) using Spark shell when the source Java class is loaded?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, avro

I am given a couple of Avro file that where generated from objects of a java class A.
Using the spark-shell (Spark 1.4.0), I can read those files into dataframes using spark-avro (version 2.0.1) and

```
val df = sqlContext.read.avro("file.avro")
```

which works fine, as long as the spark shell does not know about class A. If I add a jar, including class A to the shell and issue the same command, I get the following exception:

```
A cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.generic.IndexedRecord
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.setField(GenericData.java:569)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.setField(GenericData.java:586)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumReader.java:193)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:183)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:151)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:142)
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.next(DataFileStream.java:233)
    at org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroRecordReader.next(AvroRecordReader.java:66)
    at org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroRecordReader.next(AvroRecordReader.java:32)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.getNext(HadoopRDD.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.getNext(HadoopRDD.scala:216)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.isEmpty(Iterator.scala:256)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.isEmpty(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at com.databricks.spark.avro.AvroRelation$$anonfun$buildScan$1$$anonfun$4.apply(AvroRelation.scala:127)
    at com.databricks.spark.avro.AvroRelation$$anonfun$buildScan$1$$anonfun$4.apply(AvroRelation.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(RDD.scala:686)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(RDD.scala:686)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD.compute(UnionRDD.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I guess this is due to Avro trying to be smart and using class A if it can find it.

Is there a way to keep Avro from doing so and just using generic records directly?

Comment: I've filed a bug with spark-avro so that we make sure to look into this (I'm a contributor to that project): https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/issues/90

Comment: The same problem arises with sc.hadoopFile(path, classOf[AvroInputFormat[GenericRecord]], classOf[AvroWrapper[GenericRecord]], classOf[NullWritable]) which only works if the generating class is not in the classpath.

Answer (score 2):

To give a preliminary answer (more kind of a workaround) to my question:

If one does not need the dataframe and an RDD is good enough, I am currently using this function:

```
import org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream
import org.apache.avro.reflect.{ReflectDatumReader, ReflectData}
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

def avroFileToRDD[T](sc: SparkContext, path: String) (implicit ctag: reflect.ClassTag[T]): RDD[T] = {
    sc.binaryFiles(path).flatMap{ case(fileName, stream) =>
      val schema = ReflectData.get().getSchema(ctag.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]])
      val reader: DatumReader[T] = new ReflectDatumReader[T](schema)
      val dfs = new DataFileStream[T](stream.open, reader)
      val result = dfs.iterator().asScala.toArray // the toArray is needed to make sure that the entire stream is processed before closing it
      stream.close
      result.toIterator
    }
  }
```

This function is at least oblivious to things that can be found on the classpath and seems to work quite robustly. It has the drawback that the input stream has to be closed before leaving the flatMap and therefore each partition has to be parsed entirely.

Comment: Is there an update to this?  It seems kind of weak that the DataFrame API only works for _some_ .avro files.